# Is there a way to map a json object for the below example?

Tags: excel, mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

[excel snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUx98.png)

I am using Mule 4 and am trying to read an excel file, then convert into JSON using Dataweave and update them in salesforce.

Below is the payload which I am getting while I read the excel. I need to convert this into the requested Output Payload.

The values are dynamic. There might be more objects.

Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks.

Input Payload:

```json
{
   "X":[
      {
         "A":"Key1",
         "B":"Key2",
         "C":"Key3",
         "D":"value1",
         "E":"value2"
      },
      {
         "A":"",
         "B":"",
         "C":"Key4",
         "D":"value3",
         "E":"value4"
      },
      {
         "A":"Key5",
         "B":"Key6",
         "C":"Key7",
         "D":"Value5",
         "E":"Value6"
      },
      {
         "A":"",
         "B":"",
         "C":"Key8",
         "D":"Value7",
         "E":"Value8"
      }
   ]
}
```

Output Payload:

```json
[
   {
      "Key1":{
         "Key2":{
            "Key3":"value1",
            "Key4":"value3"
         }
      },
      "Key5":{
         "Key6":{
            "Key7":"Value5",
            "Key8":"Value7"
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "Key1":{
         "Key2":{
            "Key3":"value2",
            "Key4":"value4"
         }
      },
      "Key5":{
         "Key6":{
            "Key7":"Value6",
            "Key8":"Value8"
         }
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: So what's the actual question is? Is it the excel reading part, json transformation or salesforce integration?

Comment: @MarkBramnik Thanks for the response.  I need help with the JSON transformation.

Comment: Also please specify (add a tag) the programming language so that the relevant people could see your question...

Comment: @Gracia_L saying I need help is not a question. Please describe what is the criteria or logic to transform the data from the input to the output.

Comment: @MarkBramnik the language is DataWeave.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work.

This is JavaScript. I don't know what the underlying syntax or scripting language is for DataWeave, but between the C-family syntax and inline comments you can probably treat the JS like pseudo-code and read it well enough to recreate the logic.

````js
// I assume you started with a table structure like this:
//
//    A  B  C  D  E
//    == == == == ==
//    K1 K2 K3 v1 v2  <~ X[0]
//    __ __ K4 v3 v4  <~ X[1]
//    K5 K6 K7 v5 v6  <~ X[2]
//    __ __ K8 v7 v8  <~ X[3]
//
// So I'm going to call A,B,C,D,E "column labels"
// and the elements in `X` "rows".

// Here's the original input you provided:

input = {
  "X": [
    {
      "A":"Key1",
      "B":"Key2",
      "C":"Key3",
      "D":"value1",
      "E":"value2"
    },
    {
      "A":"",
      "B":"",
      "C":"Key4",
      "D":"value3",
      "E":"value4"
    },
    {
      "A":"Key5",
      "B":"Key6",
      "C":"Key7",
      "D":"Value5",
      "E":"Value6"
    },
    {
      "A":"",
      "B":"",
      "C":"Key8",
      "D":"Value7",
      "E":"Value8"
    }
  ]
}


// First let's simplify the structure by filling in the missing keys at
// `X[1].A`, `X[1].B` etc. We could keep track of the last non-blank
// value while doing the processing below instead, but doing it now
// reduces the complexity of the final loop.

input.X.forEach((row, row_index) => {
  (Object.keys(row)).forEach((col_label) => {
    if (row[col_label].length == 0) {
      row[col_label] = input.X[row_index - 1][col_label]
    }
  });
});

// Now X[1].A is "Key1", X[1].B is "Key2", etc.


// I'm not quite sure if there's a hard-and-fast rule that determines
// which values become keys and which become values, so I'm just going
// to explicitly describe the structure. If there's a pattern to follow
// you could compute this dynamically.

const key_column_labels = ["A","B","C"]
const val_column_labels = ["D","E"]

// this will be the root object we're building
var output_list = []

// since the value columns become output rows we need to invert the loop a bit,
// so the outermost thing we iterate over is the list of value column labels.
// our general strategy is to walk down the "tree" of key-columns and
// append the current value-column. we do that for each input row, and then
// repeat that whole cycle for each value column.
val_column_labels.forEach((vl) => {

  // the current output row we're populating
  var out_row = {}
  output_list.push(out_row)

  // for each input row
  input.X.forEach((in_row) => {

    // start at the root level of the output row
    var cur_node = out_row

    // for each of our key column labels
    key_column_labels.forEach((kl, ki) => {

      if (ki == (key_column_labels.length - 1)) {
        // this is the last key column (C), the one that holds the values
        // so set the current vl as one of the keys
        cur_node[in_row[kl]] = in_row[vl]

      } else if (cur_node[in_row[kl]] == null) {
        // else if there's no map stored in the current node for this
        // key value, let's create one
        cur_node[in_row[kl]] = {}
        // and "step down" into it for the next iteration of the loop
        cur_node = cur_node[in_row[kl]]

      } else {
        // else if there's no map stored in the current node for this
        // key value, so let's step down into the existing map
        cur_node = cur_node[in_row[kl]]
      }
    });
  });
});

console.log( JSON.stringify(output_list,null,2) )


// When I run this I get the data structure you're looking for:
//
// ```
// $ node json-transform.js
// [
//   {
//     "Key1": {
//       "Key2": {
//         "Key3": "value1",
//         "Key4": "value3"
//       }
//     },
//     "Key5": {
//       "Key6": {
//         "Key7": "Value5",
//         "Key8": "Value7"
//       }
//     }
//   },
//   {
//     "Key1": {
//       "Key2": {
//         "Key3": "value2",
//         "Key4": "value4"
//       }
//     },
//     "Key5": {
//       "Key6": {
//         "Key7": "Value6",
//         "Key8": "Value8"
//       }
//     }
//   }
// ]
// ```
````

Here's a JSFiddle that demonstrates this: https://jsfiddle.net/wcvmu0g9/

I'm not sure this captures the general form you're going for (because I'm not sure I fully understand that), but I think you should be able to abstract this basic principle.

Comment: DataWeave Is a functional language. It looks like it should be possible to translate your JavaScript in principle.

Comment: Thanks @Rod for your time and effort. I tried this one out in jsfiddle using my payload and it seemed to work fine. But I was not able to implement this in muleSoft using the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It was a challenging one. I was able to at least get the output you expect with this Dataweave code. I'll put some comments on the code.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun getNonEmpty(key, previousKey) =
    if(isEmpty(key)) previousKey else key

fun completeKey(item, previousItem) =
    {
        A: getNonEmpty(item.A,previousItem.A),
        B: getNonEmpty(item.B,previousItem.B)
    } ++ (item - "A" - "B")

// Here I'm filling up the A and B columns to have the complete path using the previous items ones if they come empty
var completedStructure = 
    payload.X reduce ((item, acc = []) -> 
        acc + completeKey(item, acc[-1])
    )

// This takes a list, groups it by a field and let you pass also what to 
// want to do with the grouped values.
fun groupByKey(structure, field, next) =
    structure groupBy ((item, i) -> item[field]) mapObject ((v, k, i1) -> 
        {
            (k): next(k,v)
        }
    )

// This one was just to not repete the code for each value field
fun valuesForfield(structure, field) =
    groupByKey(structure, "A", (key,value) -> 
        groupByKey(value, "B", (k,v) -> 
        groupByKey(value, "C", (k,v) -> v[0][field]))
    )
var valueColumns = ["D","E"]
---
valueColumns map (value, index) -> valuesForfield(completedStructure,value)
```

EDIT: valueColumns is now Dynamic

Comment: Thanks @Jorge. I tried this one and I had to make a few changes to the code while trying with my original payload and it is working fine for the Static values (valuesForfield). But the values are gonna be dynamic. I am reading an excel sheet for the input payload. So, is there any way this can be made dynamic?

Comment: Hi @Gracia_L, which is the dynamic part? The `D` and `E`? The ammount of values? Is there a limit? Or you are talking about the name of the colums (that you can drop and use the positions)?

Comment: I have attached a snippet of my input excel sheet in the question. The values 1 and 2(on the top right) are IDs are there might be more columns like this(ie, more customers). Inside each object, (eg.Eligibility) I need to group the data based on the IDs. Did I answer your question?

Comment: What you can do is to get the fist row and see which IDs or how many of them you have. Then you create a list with the columns IDs for each customer and finally, instead of a static array as I did, you iterate that array with the columns IDs using map and calling `valuesForfield(completedStructure, columnId)` inside. Makes sense?

Comment: @ Jorge Garcia, I tried adding the columnIDs to a variable. It was an array. And when I tried iterating the array, I was getting the following error.    "org.mule.runtime.core.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException: "Cannot coerce Array ([1.0, 2.0]) to Key".

Comment: @Gracia_L Check if you have an array of string or something different. I updated the code to make it dynamic as you need, just set on valueColumns the names of the columns that makes sense in your real case.